# Plastic toggle drywall anchor has come slightly away from wall but holding

Tags: drywall-anchor

I have just installed a shelf with a wardrobe rail using [plastic toggle drywall anchors](https://www.mitre10.co.nz/shop/cobra-universal-anchor-assortment-for-plasterboard-or-solid-walls-pack-of-20/p/161310).

The anchors have slightly come away from the wall (5-10mm), but are holding strongly. There is no movement in the shelves while still holding weight (clothing, as in wardrobe storage).

What are the risks with this? Will this need to be removed and the anchors replaced to ensure they remain tight to the wall? If so, can the same drill holes be used for anchors with a larger diameter than those currently used, or will I need to start from scratch on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would remove that shelf immediately, patch the holes, and try to find a way to screw its supports into the wall studs. If that shelf doesn't lend itself to being secured against the studs, find another shelf, like one with metal rails that get screwed on the studs first. When you use screws to attach to the studs, make sure to choose a screw that will not penetrate into the wall more than two inches (1/2" drywall and 1.5" stud). This is to avoid screwing into electrical wires in the wall, shorting them out and causing a fire.

Answer (score 0):

They probably just weren't tightened enough. It can take a fair amount of force to draw the wings of the toggler snugly against the backside of the wallboard.

Push the shelf or bracket tight to the wall, then snug up the screws. If they strip, start over with new togglers. You can probably reuse the same holes.